# How to disable window decorations in Cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon, window-decorations

I'm using Cinnamon, but would like to remove all window decorations -- I never use them, they only cost screen estate, and moving / resizing can be conveniently done with alt-mouse1 and alt-mouse2.

Is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT: Clarification.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with a custom [ppa providing Cinnamon](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable). I switched from the default Unity/Compiz combo because Compiz in 12.04 is a painful regression, plagued by bugs, compared to the 10.04 version (see for example [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/933776)). I got impatient waiting for correction of this and other bugs. I achieved the desired effect previously and on my 10.04 workstation with Compiz.

However, as [I understand it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_%28user_interface%29), Cinnamon is using libmuffin, and not Compiz (correct me if I'm wrong).

I am quite happy with the Cinnamon interface, in especially as the effect I got used to (equivalent to the "scale" plugin in Compiz) works without glitches. Also, I would not like to change the distribution, as I got used to Ubuntu and was very happy with the 10.04 LTS. Getting rid of window decorations is the only thing that is still missing.

Comment: Which distro is it? Cinnamon is being used further afield than for just LinuxMint.

Comment: As a matter of fact, this is Ubuntu, with the [ppa gwendal-lebihan](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable).

Comment: a possible duplicate of the above was posted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/290706/32012

Answer (score 7):

Cinnamon cannot disable or remove window decorations, according to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/3217). The option to remove window decoration is yet to be implemented.

User may instead use any of the workarounds as follows.

### Workaround 1 (easy)

Use the smallest font size for window title. Go to **System Settings > Appearance - Fonts**. Then under **Font Selection** - Window title font: change the font size from the default `10` to the smallest value `1`, then click **Select** to finish.

[image: Using the smallest window title font in Cinnamon]

Assuming the screenshot is pixel-perfect regardless of screen resolution, the height of window decoration was reduced by: 14 pixels in Cinnamon 2.2; 17 pixels in Cinnamon 3.8.

[image: Mint-Y and Mint-X themes compared as a result]

Window decoration in Cinnamon seems to use Metacity theme with Mutter/Muffin support; traditional themes do not seem to work. Different combination of themes for window borders and controls may affect the result. Some themes do not reduce the height of window decoration as much as other themes. For example, Mint-Y had worse result than Mint-X.

**Limitation**: This workaround is theme dependent. Known themes that work well with this workaround are very few: Mint-X, BlueMenta, Greybird.

### Workaround 2

Use any utility tool like [Devil's Pie](https://web.archive.org/web/20160403144942/http://foosel.org/linux/devilspie) or [Devilspie2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2), which can remove window decorations for [EWMH-compliant window managers](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/wm-spec/). This will require user configuration to remove window decoration.

For Devilspie2, open a text editor and type the following code.

```
if (get_window_type()=="WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL") then
    undecorate_window();
end
```

Save as file in `$HOME/.config/devilspie2` with any name followed by `.lua` in the filename. Run `devilspie2` to see the result. To make the changes persistent at reboot, add the command `devilspie2` to **Settings > Preferences - Startup Applications**.

[image: Undecorate window for Nemo in Cinnamon]

With above configuration, all running applications with normal window type will have no window decoration at all. [This related post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255087/125388) has my answer with details on how to use Devil's Pie and Devilspie2 to remove window decoration by application name instead.

**Limitation**: This workaround *will not* work against applications with the client-side decoration a.k.a header bar in GNOME; thus modifying the theme may be the only alternative.

### Workaround 3

Modify the theme. Cinnamon window manager, Muffin, supports Xfwm4 and Metacity themes for its window decorations: check `/usr/share/themes/THEMENAME` directory and look for either `metacity-1` or `xfwm4` subdirectory.

[This answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/333288/37165) had suggested to edit the XML file of the currently used theme:

> [...] You can edit
>
> ```
> /usr/share/themes/Mint-X/metacity-1
> ```
>
> and set all non-zero `value` properties in the `metacity-theme-1.xml` (of course you need sudo, to edit something there. A backup is useful.) [...]

The filename may vary depending on which theme in use.

Perhaps theme modification is the only "reliable" way to remove window decoration. The known limitations in other two workarounds seem redundant, except this is a tedious workaround.

**Disclaimer**: I don't use Cinnamon on daily basis and just explored again recently for experience. I did not verify the third workaround because that will take some time to test.

Tested with Cinnamon 2.2 in Linux Mint 17 (Live) and Cinnamon 3.8 in Linux Mint Debian Edition 3.

Comment: I found the theme option to be very useful. There's a very handy document on https://www.reddit.com/r/CinnamonDE/comments/4bb4re/themes_that_hide_the_titlebar_on_maximized_windows/

which details how to nearly remove the maximized title bar. It isn't visible, but you can still move your mouse up to the very top and double click to restore the original window size. Which I think worked even better than expected!

Comment: I've come up with a much quicker solution than the Tedious workaround. In metacity-theme-N.xml (where N is the version you're using (requires testing)), find `<frame-geometry name="normal"`[...]

Here, you only need to replacements:

* Replace `title_scale="medium"` with `has_title="false"`
* Under`<distance name="button_height"`[...] set the value to "0"

Comment: Ahh, you actually need to change a few other values, but everything you need to touch is inside that `<frame-geometry name="normal"`[...] code block, not everything in the whole document.

Comment: @camilla.greer The edit actually deviates from the original answer, since the source I quoted had no such detail. For the metacity theme method, I believe you should rewrite the comments into a proper answer instead.

Comment: Following my recent revisions, I am much convinced that the "tedious workaround" should just quote from the source "as it is" with no details. The Metacity theme method requires much testing (and whomever wrote the working solution deserve separate upvotes), therefore should be posted as a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just polished up the No Titlebars metacity file I use and put it on Github. It's at [No Titlebars theme for Cinnamon and the Gnome Desktop Environment](https://github.com/Fruitsalad/No-Titlebars-theme-for-Cinnamon). Hope it'll be useful to somebody.