# Launching application without titlebar and window decorations

Tags: debian, x11, xfce, desktop-environment

I want to launch VLC without the titlebar and window decoration. I'm using the following line to launch VLC:

`vlc -I dummy --no-video-deco --no-embedded-video test.mpg`

Unfortunately this doesn't remove the titlebar in XFCE. If possible it would be nice with a generic solution to remove the decorations for any application.

Currently I'm using Debian Jessie with XFCE, however this can be changed to whatever. What matters is a generic solution to this problem.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/1w4oxm/how_does_one_open_a_window_without_decoration_xfce/ceypkjq) work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It puzzles me a bit that this is so hard to achieve. Mplayer manages to do it, but has other problems which makes it useless.

Comment: Could you run just `xprop` on both `vlc` and `mplayer`? That should display properties of their windows - there's a chance you could copy something off `mplayer` that will do the trick.

Comment: Running with -noborder option on mplayer shows the motif hints: 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0. Running VLC with the options above results in 0x3, 0x3e, 0x7e, 0x0, 0x0. Changing the hints doesn't really do much. I see that VLC receives a resize event, but thats it :(

Comment: Related: KDE users refer to [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94109/125388) and Openbox users refer to [another post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108651/125388).

Answer (score 3):

Use either [Devil's Pie](https://web.archive.org/web/20160403144942/http://foosel.org/linux/devilspie) or [Devilspie2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2) to remove the window decoration. Both will likely work for any application, otherwise *will not* work against applications with the [client-side decoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-Side_Decoration).

### Using Devil's Pie

For Devil's Pie, open a text editor and type the following code.

```
(if (is (application_name) "VLC media player") (undecorate))
```

Save as file at `$HOME/.devilspie/filename.ds` with any filename of choice. Make sure the file extension is `.ds`. Finally, run `devilspie` in terminal to see the result.

### Using Devilspie2

For Devilspie2, open a text editor and type the following code.

```
if (get_application_name()=="VLC media player") then
   undecorate_window();
end
```

Save as file at `$HOME/.config/devilspie2/filename.lua` with any filename of choice. Make sure the file extension is `.lua`. Finally, run `devilspie2` in terminal to see the result.

### Devil's Pie vs. Devilspie2

If there is one thing that makes difference between these tools, it is the latter. Devilspie2 provides a convenient way to check the window name and application name for running applications, without having to run a separate command like `wmctrl -l` from other tool.

To see the debug information with Devilspie2, add the following code in the `.lua` file.

```
debug_print("Window name: " .. get_window_name());
debug_print("Application name: " .. get_application_name());
```

Exit running instance, then run `devilspie2 -d` in Terminal will print something like below.

```
Running devilspie2 in debug mode.
[...]
Window Name: VLC media player
Application name: VLC media player
Window Name: Dictionary
Application name: xfce4-dict
```

See `/usr/share/doc/devilspie2` for script example and more details.

Devil's Pie and Devilspie2 are both available in all repositories of Debian releases (oldstable, stable, testing, unstable), according to [the Debian package search results](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=devilspie&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

Tested Devil's Pie and Devilspie2 in Debian 8 Xfce and Xubuntu 14.04 (both runs Xfce 4.10), and Devilspie2 in Linux Mint Debian Edition 3 (Cinnamon 3.8).