# Disable Chrome titlebar in X11 without window manager

Tags: x11, chrome

I am creating a desktop environment to launch a Chromium-based kiosk, with this set of commands:

```
nitrogen --set-centered /usr/share/$name/$name-logo.png  --set-color="#ffffff"
xset s off; xset -dpms; xset s noblank
compiz &
exec /usr/bin/chromium-browser --kiosk --incognito --disable-hang-monitor http://localhost:8085/
```

This works, but I was wondering if there is a way to avoid using compiz. Without it, I get a gray bar accross the top of the screen, that I can only assume is the title bar. Incidentally, doing something after Chromium has launched will likely mess it up as well as it will misjudge it's size. Launching compiz after Chromium will cause the bar to go away, but for the wallpaper to be revealed underneath at the bottom of the page as Chromium moves up.

I did find the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255087/launching-application-without-titlebar-and-window-decorations), but I have not tried the Devil's Pie options, because creating the lua file and adding dependencies do not appeal to me for this situation. I've also skimmed through man pages for about everything that bash's autocomplete gives me for "x". I'm hoping a command or configurations that can set X in a state where the default window decorations will not be used. Bonus IT points for a solution that uses the default packages of an Ubuntu 14.04 install.

Comment: The window manager draws title bars. Without a WM, there are no decorations. Chrome does something weird with its windows and draws its own title bars. Did you try toggling “Use system title bar and borders” in the settings? I don't understand why you don't want to use Devil's Pie: it's the right tool to customize the layout of windows in applications that don't allow the standard way to do it.